# Divs placed in line with bootstrap WP

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

This is the link

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/

This is a WP theme made by me

I want to put two div sites in line with bootstrap.

I tried to implement this example on my website but unfortunately are placed one above the other.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_large&stacked=h

You need to do something special?
Why does not it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a two column  layout correct?

Try this

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Blog content go here
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-3">
      Side panel go here
     </div>
  </div>
```